# Delete uploaded files from the server

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, uploadify

I am using Uploadify in my ASP.NET MVC application. After the files have been uploaded, we see this:
[image]

Is it possible to remove the uploaded file (from the server) if the user hits the cancel/cross button? Any suggestion/pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: could you stream the file to a temp folder and as long as they don't hit cancel assume that they wanted to upload the file.. and do a behind the scenes async file upload after the initial file stream was successful..

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to have your server side upload action return an unique ID once the upload completes that will allow you to later identify the file on the server:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload()
{
    var fileId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    // TODO: do the uploading ...

    return Json(new { id = fileId });
}
```

and on the client keep a map between the unique file id returned by the server and the ID on the client. Then you could subscribe to the [onComplete](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/oncomplete-2/) and [onCancel](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/oncancel/) events:

```
$(function () {
    var map = {};
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'uploader': '@Url.Content("~/scripts/uploadify/uploadify.swf")',
        'script': '@Url.Action("upload")',
        'cancelImg': '@Url.Content("~/scripts/uploadify/cancel.png")',
        'auto': true,
        'removeCompleted': false,
        'multi': true,
        'onComplete': function (event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
            // once the upload succeeds we retrieve the id returned 
            // by the server and we put it in the map
            map[ID] = $.parseJSON(response).id;
        },
        'onCancel': function (event, ID, fileObj, data) {
            var fileId = map[ID];
            if (fileId) {
                // TODO: here you could send a request to the server to 
                // inform him that the user wants to delete the file with 
                // the given unique id
            }
        }
    });
});
```